# Проблемы с build Vue.js project

Tags: laravel, vue.js, webpack, vps, build

Проект laravel, в нем лежит отдельный проект vue.js. Laravel поднял, все нормально, но с vue проблемы.
Надо выложить на prod. На локальном сервере все нормально, но на vps ошибки. Сначала ругался на chulk, установил его, теперь вот. не могу устранить
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Package.json
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А разве не надо `npm install` делать? Пакетов нет, вот и ругается.

Comment: @Other, те же ошибки кидает, могу скрин кинуть

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Решил проблему, удалив папку node_modules и переустановкой npm

Answer (score 0):

У вас установлена слишком старая версия Webpack. В package.json отмечена версия 1.15.0, в то время, как пакеты требуют версию 4.

Запустите `npm install -D webpack` для обновления.

Вам может быть интересна утилита [`webpack-migrate`](https://github.com/webpack/webpack-cli/blob/master/MIGRATE.md) для перехода с первой версии на более современную.